# How can I delete thumbnails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, filereader, fileapi

I am trying to do a slideshow with images that I insert.
I already can do the insert but I can´t fix the eliminate issue.

The issue is that when i delete an image the selected image is deleted but when I am going to delete another one I delete 2 images and then 3 images and 4 images...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var p = 0;
  //Check File API support
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $('#filePhoto').change(function(event) {
      var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
      var output = document.getElementById("result");
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("teste");
      var column = document.getElementById("column");
      var _i = 1;
      var x = 0;
      if (slides.length == 0) {
        _i = 1;
      } else {
        _i = slides.length + 1;

      }
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        //Only pics
        // if(!file.type.match('image'))
        if (file.type.match('image.*')) {
          if (this.files[0].size < 2097152) {
            // continue;
            var picReader = new FileReader();
            picReader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {

              var picFile = event.target;
              var divs = document.createElement("div");

              divs.className = "teste";
              $(divs).attr('id', _i);

              if (slides.length == 0) {
                divs.style.cssText = 'display:block;';
              } else {
                divs.style.cssText = 'display:none;';
              }
              divs.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' id=" + (_i + 1) + "_img  src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                "title='' />" + "<button class='eli' id='eliminar'><i class='remove icon'></i>x</button>"
              output.insertBefore(divs, null);
              plusSlides(+1);
              var divs2 = document.createElement("div");

              for (x = 1; x <= slides.length; x++) {
                console.log(slides);
                divs2.className = "column2";
                $(divs2).attr('id', x + "_");
                divs2.innerHTML = "<img class='demo' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                  "title=''  onclick='currentSlide(" + x + ")'/>"

                column.insertBefore(divs2, null);
              }
              _i++;
            });
            //Read the image
            $('#clear, #result').show();
            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
          } else {
            alert("Image Size is too big. Minimum size is 2MB.");
            $(this).val("");
          }
        } else {
          alert("You can only upload image file.");
          $(this).val("");
        }
      }

     


    });
     $('#eliminar').click(function() {
        var a = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        //  alert(a);
        $("#" + a).remove();
        console.log($("#" + a));
        $("#" + a + "_").remove();
        plusSlides(-1);
        var elms = $("#column");
        var sd = $(".teste");
        //console.log($(elms.children()).attr("id"));
        $.each(elms.children(), function(k, v) {
          $(v).attr("id", (k + 1) + "_");
          $(v).attr("onclick", "currentSlide(" + (k + 1) + ")");
        });

        $.each(sd, function(k1, v1) {
          $(v1).attr("id", k1 + 1);
        });
      });
  } else {
    console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
  }

});
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("teste");
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("teste");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  if(slides.length!=''){
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  }
  if(slides.length>1){
    $("#next").css("display", "block");
    $("#prev").css("display", "block");

  }else {
    $("#next").css("display", "none");
    $("#prev").css("display", "none");
  }
}
```

```css
.thumbnail{

    width: 100%;
    margin:0 auto !important;
    float: left;
    height:400px !important;

}
#clear{
   display:none;
}
.result {
    margin:0 auto;
    float: left;
    width: 100% !important;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:auto;
    height:400px !important;
    background:transparent;
     border:2px dashed #e8e8e8;
     cursor:pointer;
     padding:5px;
     color:#555;
     z-index:3;
     font-family:'Segoe UI';
     font-weight:bold;

}
.eli{
  color: black;
  border:1px solid black;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:30px;
  right:5px;
  outline: inherit;
  margin-bottom: -10px !important;
  z-index: 2000000;
}

.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;

}
.column  {
  left:0;
  width:1200px;

}
.bstimeslider {

width:500px;
height:40px;
background:#ccc;
position:relative;
}
#leftArrow {

width:40px;
height:40px;
background:#ff0000;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
}

#rightArrow {

width:40px;
height:40px;
background:#ff0000;
position:absolute;
right:0px;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  top:42%;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select:none;

}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.prev {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
  float: left;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.blok{
  display: block !important;
}
.nonee{
  display: none!important;
}
.uploader {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:auto;
  height:400px;
  background:transparent;
   border:2px dashed #e8e8e8;
   cursor:pointer;
   padding:5px;
   color:#555;
   z-index:3;
   font-family:'Segoe UI';
   font-weight:bold;
   }



#filePhoto{
    display:none;
}

.lol{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:402px;
    top:-1px;
    left:-1px;
    border:none;
    background-color: #eee;
}



.uploadd {
  padding:10px !important;
  margin-top:90px;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uploadd">
  <div id="uploader" class="uploader ">
    <output id="result" class=" lol" />
    <label for="filePhoto">
      <span id="butao" class="circular ui icon button file-button" 
      style="position:absolute;top:43%;left:47%;margin-left:3.500 
       !important;border-radius:100%;background:#2185d0;">
        <i style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;font-size:24px;color:white;" 
        class="plus icon xa">Add</i>
        
          </span>
        </label>
    <input class="file" type="file" name="filePhoto" id="filePhoto" multiple/>
    <a class="prev" name="prev" id="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094</a>
    <a class="next" name="next" id="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>

  <output class="column" id="column" name="column" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve] with enough html and code to reproduce the issue! - Also `.live` is deprecated for `.on`

Comment: I created you a snippet using VERY OLD jQuery. Change the .live to .on and the version to a much newer one before continuing. Then fix the console errors you have

Comment: I have updated the snippet and changed the .live to .change, but the eliminate function doesnt work with .click

Comment: 1. IDs need to be unique. 
2. change jQuery from 1.6.4 to 1.9+ or 3+ if you do not need to support IE8. 
3. change to `$('#column').on("click","eliminar",function() {` - HOWEVER there is such a mess of DOM and jQuery access that I broke it while trying to refactor, please have a look so you get the idea of what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/zbp8kzag/

Comment: Also do the same delegation with the DEMO image

Comment: I inserted event.stopPropagation(), event.preventDefault(); on #eliminar function and solved my problem, the thing now is that I stil have the live method and only seems to work with this...

Comment: Change the jQuery version!!!

Comment: Just did i put 3.1.1 and still have the same result

Comment: What result? Console errors?

Comment: No errors and when I click nothing happen

Comment: Work in progress: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/r3ovv4pu/